# Need help in emailing errors

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to get my errors emailed, It gets logged successfully but no email gets sent! There is no traceback or any other errors, just that if an error code 500 is encountered, it logs it but doesn't send any email to the admins!

I have tried many solutions on the internet and none have worked!

Here is a part of my settings.py:

```
ADMINS = [('Prithvi', '<email1>')]


#Email Settings

MAILER_LIST = ['<email1>']
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<email2>' #EDITED
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<password>'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME = True
SERVER_EMAIL = '<email2>'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '<email2>'

#Logger and Handler settings

# Python logging package
import logging

# Standard instance of a logger with __name__
stdlogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Custom instance logging with explicit name
dbalogger = logging.getLogger('dba')

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'development_logfile': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': r'C:/Users/Prithvi/Desktop/Prithvi/django/pd1/tmp/django_dev.log',###
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'production_logfile': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': r'C:/Users/Prithvi/Desktop/Prithvi/django/pd1/var/log/django/django_production.log',###
            'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*100, # 100MB
            'backupCount' : 5,
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'dba_logfile': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false','require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',###
            'filename': r'C:/Users/Prithvi/Desktop/Prithvi/django/pd1/var/log/dba/django_dba.log',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['console'],
    },  
    'loggers': {
        'coffeehouse': {
            'handlers': ['development_logfile','production_logfile'],
         },
        'dba': {
            'handlers': ['dba_logfile'],
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['development_logfile','production_logfile'],
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ['development_logfile'],
        },
    }
}
```

I just wish I knew what is causing this and there isn't much info on this topic on the official documentation to help me either!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your settings.py looks good. A while ago i tried the same thing but realized gmail doesn't allow you to send emails this easily. Check your gmail inbox you must have  received an email saying "attempt was blocked". It marks your application "not safe enough". 
You could go to other mail service providers like zoho and use their smtp servers instead. 
Hope that helps !!

```
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        #'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
 }

 'loggers': {
'django': {
    'handlers': ['file', 'console', 'mail_admins',],
    'propagate': True,
    'level': 'DEBUG',
},
```

Comment: Hmm, well I have not got such a mail in the inbox, which makes me suspect the issue is else where. I will try using some other smtp servers and let you know if it worked...

Comment: EDIT: I was going through the code again and I realised I goofed up in setting EMAIL_HOST_USER and made typo as EMAIL_HOST, which was already set above, I made the change and I also tried using SendinBlue as my smtp service, but still no luck!

Comment: EDIT: I just tried to normally send a mail using manage.py shell and the send_mail() function, and it worked, but it is not mailing me any errors, how is this possible?

Comment: can you edit your settings.py as above? i think the missing 'mail_admins' is causing the problem.

Comment: You mean in the logging section of my settings.py ?

Comment: Yes, That about fixed everything! Thanks for the help! Could not have fixed it without your help!

Comment: My rep is still too low for the upvotes to be visible, lol. I should probably go and answer some questions or ask more of them!

Comment: EDIT: I actually do have another question, if you don't mind me putting it here @SaswathMishra . I get the emails now, but I get an email for each individual error I receive. I would like to know a way of how to email the errors that happen at once to be mailed in one single mail, like if 4 errors were encountered when I clicked a url on my website, then I wish them all to be in one email, not 4 different emails. I am especially worried about this since, if I get a lot errors due to some reason and it sends a 100 emails to me with each error, google might block it as spam, which is not ideal.